# Knockout.js failure to update previously null children

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to do a fairly simple partial update. I update a view models' property "person", which is initially null, with an object with its own child property "lastName". This fails with "no method person.lastName()" when trying to notify subscribers.

Fiddle demonstrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/P4Jd3/4/

HTML

```
<body>
  <hr/>
  <div data-bind="text: rootdata"></div>
  <hr/>
  <div data-bind="if: person">
    <div data-bind="text: person.lastName()?person.lastName()+'###':'foo'">
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <input type="submit" data-bind="click: updatedata" value="update data"></input>
</body>
```

JS:

```
newdata = {
    person: {
        lastName: "Mr.Bar"
    },
    rootdata : "Root 2"
}

model = {
    self: this,
    person : ko.observable(null),
    rootdata : ko.observable("Init root"),
    updatedata: function() {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(newdata, {}, model);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

At the moment of update, I get an error stating that Object function [ko observable junk string] has no method lastName().

```
Message: TypeError: Object function d(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!d.equalityComparer||!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return this}b.r.Wa(d);return c} has no method 'lastName';
Bindings value: text: person.lastName()?person.lastName()+'###':'foo'
```

That person.lastName()+"##" is needed for combining property values with optional text formatting, depending on whether some properties are non-empty.

I am out of ideas on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Your person object doesn't have a lastname property, let alone an observable when you call applyBindings. It is only created when you call upadteData.

I usually initialise my view model with blank observables:

```
model = {
    self: this,
    person : ko.observable({ lastName: ko.observable('')}),
    rootdata : ko.observable("Init root"),
    updatedata: function() {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(newdata, {}, model);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Comment: I feel there is a valid case for a situation where properties may be null, as in this case. That's why there is that if:person wrapper around the element using person.lastName.
What I'm curious about is whether or not this kind of usage is possible at all, or not?

Comment: Well, they can be null, but you are trying to call lastName() in your binding, but when you create your model, there is no such observable on it, so that can never work. In fact, you are initialising your person object as null, so it can't even get the property out to check whether it is null.

Comment: Did you run the fiddle? There you can see that the error occurs only when you click the "update data" button, which should load the data with person & lastName. I'm using Chrome dev tools to see that, but I'm pretty sure Firebug will show it too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use-case for the `with` binding. If you replace `if: person` with `with: person`, it simplifies your code and just works:

```
<div data-bind="with: person">
    <div data-bind="text: lastName() ? lastName()+'###' : 'foo'"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/P4Jd3/5/

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the `()` from `lastName` property. Because it's not observable property

**OR** edit your code to define new model for your data with observables properties